# Destructuring nested map of maps - Clojure

Tags: collections, clojure, destructuring

I studying about destructuring in Clojure. I learned a bit and now I can able to destructure two-level nested maps. How can I destructure the deepest nested maps? I leaving here an example map that I tried to restructure. Can you show me some easy-to-understand examples of how to destructure that nested maps?

```
(def my-nested-map-2 {:id 1 :name {:first "ali" :last "veli"}})

(let [{id :id {first :first, last :last} :name} my-nested-map-2]
  (println id first last))



;==>this map I would like to destructure.
(def my-nested-map-3 {:id 1 :name {:first "ali" :last "veli"} :surname {:snf "foo" :snl "bar" :location {:country "usa"}} :age 26})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same exact way you have nested the destructuring initially, but one level deeper. Notice how I also used `:keys` to avoid repeating the names:

```
(let [{:keys
       [id age]
      
       {:keys [first last]}
       :name

       {:keys [snf snl], {:keys [country]} :location}
       :surname}
      my-nested-map-3]
  ...)
```

But notice that I also added quite a bit of formatting on top to make it comprehensible. Nested destructuring usually makes things more confusing than they need to be. E.g. notice how much cleaner this code is, where there's just a single level of destructuring:

```
(let [{:keys [id name surname age]} my-nested-map-3
      {:keys [first last]} name
      {:keys [snf snl location]} surname
      ;; Why is `location` under `:surname` in the first place?
      {:keys [location]} surname]
  ...)
```

The only downside in this particular case is that it brings more names to the local scope than needed, and it even shadows the built-in `name`. If that's an issue, you can always rename things in one of the destructuring or avoid a single level with an explicit getter, like `(:name my-nested-map-3)`.

Comment: Hello, thank you for separating your time that was great for me. 

;; Why is `location` under `:surname` in the first place?
I just wanted to make a more confusing nested map to get an example.  there is no logic ground for it.

Answer (score 1):

While native destructuring can be sufficient, I often find it easier to use the [plumbing](https://github.com/plumatic/plumbing) library instead.

```
(use '[plumbing.core])
(let [data {:id 1 :name {:first "ali" :last "veli"}
            :surname {:snf "foo" :snl "bar" :location {:country "usa"}}
            :age     26}]
   (letk [[id name surname] data
          [first last] name
          [snf snl location] surname
          [country] location]
     country))
```

Comment: Looks great! Thank you!  But can't able to run it. Do you have any idea why? :)  I tried to print values id name etc.